# Getting a text area in the system tray

Tags: c#

i was just wondering what i need to research to be able to have a programme that is in the system tray, when the user clicks the programme icon, just above the system tray a small text area appears allowing the user to type in a search condition. There is plenty of resources for c# and getting your programme in the system tray, but then it just opens as normal, which is not quite what i am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `NotifyIcon.Click` event and show your form in the desired location.

For example:

```
var screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
form.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Right - form.Width;
form.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Bottom - form.Height;
```

Comment: i assume from my attmepts i need a using statement of some sort ?

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this is to use a standard WinForms window which contains a single text box and has no border.  This window can then be displayed and positioned as normal (likely using many of the existing samples) but will appear as a floating text box.

```
var form = new MyTextBoxForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
// position the form
form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this [Make your program in the system + add a menu](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3336751) you could try editing the menu, like you'd do a regular menu with toolstrips.... and change the label by a textbox.

Just a random idea.